# I wanna run the 'rich' command again after the print

Tags: python, if-statement

I basically want the input command to run again after the 3nd 'if' command

```
rich = input("Are you rich?(yes/no): ")
if rich == "yes":
    print("damn gg")

if rich == "no":
    print("poor bastard")

if rich != "yes" or "no":
    print("it's a yes or no question dumbass")
    rich()

#expected answer: 
#it's a yes or no question dumbass
#Are you rich?(yes/no):
```

Comment: `rich` is a string, not a function, so `rich()` is an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if rich != "yes" or "no":` should be `if rich != "yes" and rich != "no":`. But the issue here is that the `rich()` function's name was overwritten with the line `rich = input(...)`. Also, your indentation was messed up.

```
def rich():
    print("whatever")
    

answer = input("Are you rich?(yes/no): ")
if answer == "yes":
    print("damn gg")

if answer == "no":
    print("poor bastard")

if answer != "yes" and answer != "no":
    print("it's a yes or no quesiton dumbass")

rich() # output: whatever
```

It's not clear what the `rich()` command does though unless this code is supposed to be in the function itself. If that's the case, the code should just be in a loop:

```
def rich():
    answer = input("Are you rich?(yes/no): ")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("damn gg")
    
    if answer == "no":
        print("poor bastard")
    
    if answer != "yes" and answer != "no":
        print("it's a yes or no quesiton dumbass")


while True:
    rich()
```

Or just:

```
while True:
    rich = input("Are you rich?(yes/no): ")
    if rich == "yes":
        print("damn gg")

    if rich == "no":
        print("poor bastard")

    if rich != "yes" and rich != "no":
        print("it's a yes or no quesiton dumbass")
```

Comment: Sorry, I've never used stackoverflow so I didn't really get how to use the indentation here. But I got it now and fixed it. It was always fine in the code so no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a while loop over this until they give an answer you want and then break from it.
It would look something like this:

```py
while True:
    rich = input("Are you rich?(yes/no): ")
    if rich == "yes":
        print("damn gg")
        break
    if rich == "no":
        print("poor bastard")
        break
    if rich != "yes" and rich != "no":
        print("it's a yes or no question dumbass")
```

Comment: Tbh I'm just trying out random codes and slowly increasing the levels to get more experience. The first one seems easier to me. But it's good to know about the other methods too.

Comment: yeah, while loops are very similar to if statements so they aren't too hard to understand if you are just starting.